# Number agreement question

Tags: grammatical-number

I have always been wondering how I should determine the number of noun in this case: Compare the ***effect*** of the two policies. Or should I put as: Compare the ***effects*** of the two policies? Or is there any better way to address this question?

Contextualizing the question: The government is considering two policy options: monetary policy or fiscal policy. Each policy has a different implication on the economy. Economists want to compare the **effect/effects** of the two policies.

Comment: Even if discussing only one policy, might not that policy have multiple effects?

Comment: Economists want to compare the effect each policy might have [on employment]. Your original two suggestions are always ambiguous, but the specific context may make them plain to understand. You can choose whether you want to focus on the policies themselves, or on their effects, but you still have to provide some clarity to what effect/s go with what policies.

Comment: You can check that the noun **effect** has both count and non-count usages. 'The effect of the two policies was the eradication of  mediumpox, glumps and BT' shows a non-count usage with various consequences being conceptually lumped together, while 'The effects of the two policies were the eradication of mediumpox, glumps and BT' emphasises individual consequences. // _However_, 'Economists want to compare the effects of the two policies' looks at different consequences, needing considering separately, so the plural count usage is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Only a plural is possible, this being so because if you are going to make a comparison you have to begin with at least two elements.

- Economists want to compare the effects of the two policies.